# Sudden battery drain in brand new Accord

Tags: honda, battery, accord

The other day we stopped for lunch for about an hour on a long trip in a 2012 Honda Accord EX-L 4 cylinder. When we came back the battery had drained so much the car had to be jump started. The headlights were not on (but even if they were, 1 hour is not usually enough to drain batter that far).

The car is 3 months old and at 5k-miles.

Dealer has checked and cannot find any issue. It has been running fine ever since.

Could anyone know what might have happened?

Comment: Can you add some more info?How brand new like on the way home from the lot new?Did you drive back and it restart ok after that.Or did you drive it straight back to the dealer?

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue with my last car, I even took it in to an electric shop and they couldn't pinpoint the problem. Low and behold after many head scratching days and hair pulling nights I found it to be a problem with a misplaced fused in the fuse-box under the dash. One of the fuses was inserted wrong, between two sockets, which meant there was an open draw on the electric current at all times, draining the battery in less than an hour consistently.

Check that out, might be your problem as well. Other than that I'd check to see if you have any audio or aftermarket electronic devices incorrectly installed.

Comment: I'll look into it. But in my case it has happened only once. There are absolutely no aftermarket installations.

Comment: Just thought I'd put that idea in your head, for I was completely flabbergasted when after months of dealing with this issue, to find it was such a simple thing as a misplaced fuse in the fuse box. Hell, even the auto electric shop missed it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with my brand new Accord Touring 2017 ( [What are "normal" battery recharge needs for modern cars?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43223/what-are-normal-battery-recharge-needs-for-modern-cars?rq=1) ). I don't know the cause (both dealer's and my own research showed no issues). Perhaps it was a fluke: extra drain as I was trying all features on the new car. But, if that issue starts to appear in many new accords, I hope Honda looks harder into it. Just in case (to reduce my "battery anxiety"), I bought a "battery monitoring gage" (to know when to manually recharge, if needed) and a "portable lithium battery" (to jump start, if needed).